# Zend framework and jQuery Mobile, unable to import the Javascript and CSS files

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

Hi I'm trying to import jQuery mobile JS in to my ZEND project but is not working.
 solved ***
If I do this (import a general style sheet that I wrote):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mysite.com/zend/service/css/general_style.css"/>
```

**the style is loaded and works fine**,

but if I do the same thing whit the jQuery style file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mysite.com/zend/service/css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css"/>
```

The style will not be imported.

This is what will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
```

but i like the files to be store in my local folder.

SOLUTION: echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css'); **

Same thing for the JS files: (not working).

```
 echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js','text/javascript');
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Are the CSS and JS files all stored in your local, public folder, eg `zend/service/css`?

Comment: yes, and the JS are in the js dir. (I just solved the CSS part and edited the question)

Comment: What happens if you try to open the JS file directly in your browser, ie `http://www.mysite.com/zend/service/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js` (assuming I've interpreted your application's path correctly)

Comment: I can view the file correctly

Comment: What does your rendered HTML page source for the `HeadScript` call look like (view-source in your browser)?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/zend/service/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/zend/service/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/zend/service/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>

Comment: and clicking on the link I see the correct JS file

Comment: Why is it showing up three times (twice for the uncompressed version, once for the minified one)? You must have other `HeadScript` calls appending the file

Comment: Thanks for the help! I finally found the solution: <? echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js'),'text/javascript')
   ->prependFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'),'text/javascript')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using:

```
<? echo $this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js'),'text/javascript') 
    ->prependFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'),'text/javascript')
```

hope this will save some time to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks alright though you don't need to prefix your paths with a forward slash when using the `BaseUrl` helper.

Try the following

1. Ensure the file `public/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js` exists and is readable by your webserver (permissions 644)
2. Try the following `HeadScript` call in your layout

   ```
   <?php echo $this->headScript()
       ->appendFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js')) ?>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Phil, I tried but is still not working, how do I test if the the file has permission 644?